# How to post Array of Dictionaries, which is stored in NSArray var in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

I have JSON response of type (Array of dictionaries) coming of POST request using Alamofire

```
 "emergency_contacts":[   (
    {
    "first_name" = bxbx;
    "last_name" = yahd;
},
    {
    "first_name" = Bills;
    "last_name" = yah;
}
)]
```

I'm saving response like this and Im getting it successfully

```
let tempArray = userData["emergency_contacts"] as! NSArray
LoginSingleton.shared.usersList= tempArray
```

Now I want to POST this Array of Dictionaries in another request How do I do that?Im post other parameters too so please suggest me some method using multipart.Thanks
This is how I'm trying

```
multipartFormData.append("\(LoginSingleton.shared.usersList)".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "emergency_contacts")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to convert your array of dictionaries to data using `data(withJSONObject:options:)` function of [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) like this:

```
do {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: LoginSingleton.shared.usersList)
    multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "emergency_contacts")
} catch {
    // Something whent srong with serialization proccess
    print(error)
}
```